# appending each line in a txt list

Tags: vb.net, append, line, text-files

I  have a list of file names and  there locations as follows:

> c:\ICT\AUTOCAD_2010\Customisations\20090409\20090409.lsp
>   c:\ICT\AUTOCAD_2010\Customisations\Advanced Offset\LSP\ADVANCED
>   OFFSET.lsp c:\ICT\AUTOCAD_2010\Customisations\LockDWG\LSP\LockDWG.lsp
>   c:\ICT\AUTOCAD_2010\LSP\acad2010doc.lsp

The list is very basic but should be appended to say:

> (load “c:\ICT\AUTOCAD_2010\Customisations\20090409\20090409.lsp”)
>   (load “c:\ICT\AUTOCAD_2010\Customisations\Advanced Offset\LSP\ADVANCED OFFSET.lsp”) 
>   (load “c:\ICT\AUTOCAD_2010\Customisations\LockDWG\LSP\LockDWG.lsp”)
>   (load “c:\ICT\AUTOCAD_2010\LSP\acad2010doc.lsp”)

How can this be done with VB.net?

Comment: Is the original list in a file? Should the result be written to a file? Or are you using some other data structures?

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not too large then you can do the following:

```
Dim fileContents As String, contentArray As String()
Dim updateContents As New StringBuilder("")

'read the file contents in
fileContents = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\TestInput.txt")
'split the contents on the space delimiter - this method will fail if you have a space in your filename
contentArray = fileContents.Split(" "c)
'loop through each file found in the data and format as required
For Each fileString As String In contentArray
    updateContents.Append(String.Format("(load {0}{1}{0}) ", Chr(34), fileString))
Next
'write out the newly formatted file
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\TestOuput.txt", updateContents.ToString, True)
```